# Only execute service once despite number of notifies in Chef

Tags: chef-infra

I currently have two files being created via templates in Chef. Both these templates currently notify a service when it is modified.

```rb
template '/etc/file1' do
    source 'file1.erb'
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode '644'
    notifies :restart, 'service[foo]'
end

template '/etc/file2' do
    source 'file2.erb'
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode '600'
    notifies :restart, 'service[foo]'
end

service "foo" do
    action :nothing
end
```

Is there a way where I can call the service only when either of these files are changed? The reason for this is because I want to avoid two instances of "foo" executing if both files were changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example 'foo' service will be notified only once (and executed only once) and only if any of the files changes. Exactly as you expect.

Comment: To add one more bit: The default [notification timing](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#timers) is `:delayed`. In case you would want multiple restarts, there would be `:immediate(ly)`.

Comment: Oh that's really neat! Nice addition for clarification regarding multiple restarts as well @StephenKing. Thank you both very much! :)